# Implementing PBKDF2

Tags: vba, ms-access, hash, passwords, ms-access-2016

I've been building a custom access DB and I have added a login screen with usernames and passwords. Originally I used SHA1 and no salt to hash the passwords. (I know that's not very secure, but it was only meant for a few users and contained no personal information)

However corporate has seen the DB application and they want to install it and add more users and features. I'd like to start using Salts and PBKDF2 to has the passwords, but I couldn't find any information on PBKDF2 with MS Acess specifically. Below are the 2 functions I pieced together

```
Public Function PBKDF2(pass As String, salt As String, inter As Int32) As String

    Set oT = CreateObject("System.Text.UTF8Encoding")
    Dim bytes() As Byte

    TextToHash = oT.GetBytes_4((pass))
    SaltBytes = oT.GetBytes_4((salt))

    Set oRFC = CreateObject("System.Security.Cryptography.Rfc2898DeriveBytes( (TextToHash), (SaltBytes), inter )")

    bytes() = oRFC.GetBytes(16)

    PBKDF2 = ByteArrayToHex(bytes())

End Function


Private Function ByteArrayToHex(ByRef ByteArray() As Byte) As String

    Dim lb As Long, ub As Long
    Dim l As Long, strRet As String
    Dim lonRetLen As Long, lonPos As Long
    Dim strHex As String, lonLenHex As Long

    lb = LBound(ByteArray)
    ub = UBound(ByteArray)
    lonRetLen = ((ub - lb) + 1) * 3
    strRet = Space$(lonRetLen)
    lonPos = 1

    For l = lb To ub
        strHex = Hex$(ByteArray(l))
        If Len(strHex) = 1 Then
            strHex = "0" & strHex
        End If
        If l <> ub Then
            Mid$(strRet, lonPos, 3) = strHex & " "
            lonPos = lonPos + 3
        Else
            Mid$(strRet, lonPos, 3) = strHex
        End If
    Next l

    ByteArrayToHex = strRet

End Function
```

I get the error

> "ByRef argument mismatch"

Is there a better way to implement PBKDF2 in Access VBA, or is there a fix for these functions?

Comment: 1. Rfc2898DeriveBytes is the way to go, you just need to figure out how to pass the arguments and debug. 2. Where does the error occur? 3. Why do you need to convert the binary to hex? Just save the binary and later compare.

Comment: The error occurs at PBKDF2 = ByteArrayToHex(bytes), but it's a compile error not a runtime error. Also, they don't need to be converted to Hex, but that's how I stored the SHA1 hashes and was trying to be consistent

Comment: Figure out how to pass the arguments, read the documentation.

Comment: I don't know what language you are using, but it is _not_ VBA! First clue: `inter As Int32`. The correct VBA type is `Long`. When I correct the code in Access, and run it, it fails at the `Set oRFC = CreateObject("...` line with `Error 429: ActiveX component can't create object`. Please edit your code so it compiles in VBA, and fix the `CreateObject` line, and resubmit your question if you have any further problems.

Comment: Can't fix that `CreateObject`, though. Afaik `Rfc2898DeriveBytes` is not available through COM. You need to make a custom COM class using a .Net programming language (VB.Net, C#, C++)

Comment: Since PBKDF2 rely on hmac and sha1, an alternative would be to use `System.Security.Cryptography.HMACSHA1` in a loop. See https://www.sjoerdlangkemper.nl/2016/05/25/iterative-password-hashing/

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth See [Rfc2898DeriveBytes Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rfc2898derivebytes(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1) `<ComVisibleAttribute(True)>
Public Class Rfc2898DeriveBytes
 Inherits DeriveBytes`

Comment: @zaph I guess I didn't word it well. You can't fix it because the VBA doesn't support constructors with parameters. I don't know of a workaround outside of using a different programming language to create a com class that doesn't require them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@zaph and @EricvonAsmuth both have valid points. It looks like `Rfc2898DeriveBytes` can't be directly used in VBA. It might be simpler to try another path.

There are native VB6/VBA SHA1 implementations you can find online. You can test these against online SHA1 generators to verify validity.

Depending on your comfort level with .NET and COM, this approach might be easier.